# How exactly are criteria of conditional access for client state (domain-joined) evaluated

Tags: windows-10, active-directory, azure-activedirectory

When evaluating conditional access policies within AAD, Microsoft offers to check the device-state. This includes also checks for "Azure AD joined" and "Hybrid joined".

If a client is reaching Microsoft via browser (eg. outlook.office.com), **how exactly does Microsoft then evaluate, if the client is domain joined or not?**

My guess is: They are reading a clients certificate via browser-calls, but I could not find any resources about it.

Answer (score 0):

No certificates are involved -
the devices in question must be in a Domain join or have
[Microsoft Intune](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/what-is-intune).

The information gained via the above tools can be used by
[Mobile device management (MDM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/)
and
[mobile application management (MAM)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-management).

Hybrid Azure AD joined devices require network line of sight to
your on-premises domain controllers periodically.
Without this connection, devices become unusable.

Azure AD joined devices are signed into using an organizational
Azure AD account.

For both methods, the nature of the device is known in advance when
the request for resources is made.